# Pushing changes to HEAD detached from origin in git

Tags: git, branch, git-push, git-pull

I have been using `git` for some time already but this is the first time I have to deal with a master and a branch.

It happens on a directory /D I have created a branch and then checked out that branch on other directory /S. From /S I commited and pushed some changes. But when I want to pull those changes under /D I get the message that I'm "Already up-to-date". I thought maybe it was related to `.gitignore`, but it seems not.

**Note:** /D directory is local on my machine and /S directory is a mounted directory (on a Windows machione) from a network shared drive.

### Situation within directory /D

`git status` command shows:

```
USER@PC MINGW64 /d/epptra2 (v2.8_beta_1.5_branch)
$ git status
On branch v2.8_beta_1.5_branch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch'.
```

And `git branch` command shows:

```
USER@PC MINGW64 /d/epptra2 (v2.8_beta_1.5_branch)
$ git branch -a
  master
  origin
* v2.8_beta_1.5_branch
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch
```

### Situation within directory /S

`git status` command shows:

```
USER@PC MINGW64 /s/epptra2 ((4c27924...))
$ git status
HEAD detached from origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch
```

And `git branch` command shows:

```
USER@PC MINGW64 /s/epptra2 ((4c27924...))
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached from origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch)
  master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch
```

### Questions

**How can I get the changes I pushed to the branch under directory /S to be reflected under directory /D?** And **why was the HEAD detached from origin?** Is there any command I may have done to detach the HEAD by mistake? If so, how can I fix this?

I had been pushing changes from /D and my collegues have been pulling changes from that branch with no issues. I still don't see why doing some update from another repository pointing to same branch would make this issue.

Comment: The way you (or someone) get (or got) a detached HEAD is by asking Git to `git checkout --detach` a branch name, or by using `git checkout` with something that is not a branch name, such as a tag name or remote-tracking name. `origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch` is a remote-tracking name, so `git checkout origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch` will result in a detached HEAD. This is normal! Just `git checkout <whatever-branch>` to change it.

Comment: Note, however, that any commits anyone made *in this repository* while *using the detached HEAD* will become very hard to find (and eventually, will be garbage-collected). Meanwhile, if *you* didn't do this, someone else did. Why? Find out who and why before you change it.

Comment: Last, note that when pushing to another repository, if that other repository has an index and work-tree—as any non-bare repository will—the other Git may reject your push. This is the default if you push to the branch they have checked-out. In general you *should not* push to non-bare repositories. Use a bare repository, which is one with no work-tree, so that no one can be doing any work *in* that repository, so that your push cannot break their in-progress work.

Comment: @torek Would it be possible for you to explain and publish your thoughts as an answer? I would certainly upvote. 
I'm working under a bare repository. The one doing changes by now was only me. And as you suspected I did checkout remotes/origin/v2.8_beta_1.5_branch, which is a tag I did push to be able to do checkout from other computers. 
Maybe this isn't best way to manage the situation I had, which was I found a bug and had to create a new branch and ask my collegues to checkout that branch and continue new commits from there till I could solve that bug.

Comment: As you said I couldn't push changes from the branch checked out. I don't get yet which is the philosophy behind this. I thought many people would be able to work under same branch. Although I may have set the branch in a wrong way. I still can perform the change from the original directory but I'm still wondering why I'm not being able to push  changes from the repository with the checked out branch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm concerned that the question itself is not focused enough, and as a result, I'll produce another mega-answer that really should refer to you a good Git book.I think you're starting with misconceptions about version control in general and Git's implementation in specifics, as *branch names* have no actual meaning in Git. What matters are the *commits*. The branch names are just a way to *find* commits.

Comment: Commits themselves are snapshots of files, so in that sense, Git contains files—but Git is really about the commits. You have a whole commit (and hence a whole snapshot) or none of it (hence no files at all). The files inside each commit are frozen for all time, and in a special Git-only format; the files you see and work with are not the files that are in the commit.

Comment: Even without introducing more people and repositories, this whole structure—of your files being separate and different from Git's commits—takes some getting used to. Throw in multiple repositories, which work by sending each other whole commits (not files) and require that each user take various actions to incorporate new commits, and it gets complicated.

Comment: Well, I may have get the wrong conception about branches and tags then. Is there no way to say this commit is for this branch? I still don't see how to get another repository to update the new branch. If you can refer me to any good book I would appreciate.

Comment: I believe my problem now is that master has the bug and the branch is the one working. Maybe the question would be how to make the branch as master and the master as a new branch, if that's possible. If so I may have to create a new question I believe or edit this one.

Comment: Commits are just commits; branch names are just *pointers*, pointing to some commit. This means that one commit can be on ten branches, or no branches at all. If you add a branch name, commits that *were* on 1 branch may now be on 2. If you delete a branch name, commits that *were* on 5 branches may now be on 4. When you move branch names around, the set of commits that are findable from those names, changes.

Comment: There's a decent (and free) book at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 and in this case you might look at http://think-like-a-git.net/ too.